# Why is close() method highlighted as redundant in Intellij, when using CSVPrinter from apcache.commons?

Tags: apache, csv, apache-commons

I am using CSVPrinter class from apache.commons.csv, and I am trying to print some lines in a csv file. As I know, we need to call `close()` method on a `FileWriter`, after the writing is done. And based on that assumption, I tried to call `CSVPrinter.close()`.However, IntelliJ IDEA warns me that this method is redundant. Besides, examples in https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-apache-commons-csv/ does not include this method, either. I want to know why is that method redundant and if I just use .flush() everything will be alright?

Here is an example copied from website mentioned above.

```java
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CSVWriter {
    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE = "./sample.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (
                BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE));

                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                        .withHeader("ID", "Name", "Designation", "Company"));
        ) {
            csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "Sundar Pichai ♥", "CEO", "Google");
            csvPrinter.printRecord("2", "Satya Nadella", "CEO", "Microsoft");
            csvPrinter.printRecord("3", "Tim cook", "CEO", "Apple");

            csvPrinter.printRecord(Arrays.asList("4", "Mark Zuckerberg", "CEO", "Facebook"));

            csvPrinter.flush();

// I added the following line
            csvPrinter.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Both `close()` and `flush()` are redundant here, the former because of the try-with-resources, and the latter because of the former.

Comment: @user207421 would you please explain in more detail? I did not get it.

Comment: 1. The try-with-resources statement provides an automatic close at the end of its scope. 2. Flush is redundant before close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user207421 explained in the comments.

**First:** The try-with-resources statement provides an automatic close at the end of its scope.

**Second:** Flush is redundant before close.